# What is the shortcut to activate the keyframe?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

In a window with a keyframe, move the active keyframe by using the direction key to move it.
But I don't know the shortcut when I want to activate another keyframe.
It's a little uncomfortable to click with the mouse, but can't I click with the keyboard?

Comment: What do you mean by "a window with a keyframe"? (Timeline, Graph Editor, somehing else?) You can just hit the left or right keys to move along the timeline and Shift-Left /Right moves to the start or end.

Comment: to select a keyframe you need to use your mouse as when you select an object in the 3D view

Comment: I want to say everything about keyframes. Grease pencils, timelines, etc I know I can press the keyframe with my mouse. I want to know how to do it with a keyboard. The mouse is uncomfortable. My eng is bad. sorry

Comment: to select all the keyframes press A, to select all the keyframe that are after the blue playhead put your cursor after the playhead and press Ctrl left click

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thnk there is no way that we select keyframe in blue playhead.